# Symfony2 caching issue

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create a "Hello World" with Symfony2 and it seemed to run the first time, but whatever changes I do and save the controller - no changes on the front end whatsoever.

This is how my controller looks like:

```
namespace Test\CalcBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class CalcController {

    public function indexAction($name) {

        return new Response("<html><body>Hello " . $name . "!</body></html>");

    }

}
```

No matter how I change this file - nothing reflects in the browser. Is this some kind of caching going on and if so how do I disable it? Browser is not caching it, because if I change the last bit of the url - it reflects on the page.

I'm running this in my development environment - Windows 8, PHP 5.5.3 (XAMPP), Apache.

**UPDATE:** Sorry, forgot to add, the URL I'm using is this:

```
http://localhost/test/web/app_dev.php/Calc/name
```

**UPDATE2:** app/config/routing.yml:

```
test_calc:
    resource: "@TestCalcBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

src/Test/CalcBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml:

```
test_calc_homepage:
    pattern:  /Calc/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: TestCalcBundle:Default:index }
```

**UPDATE3:** The exact version of Symfony2 I'm using is **2.3.5**

**UPDATE4:** Found the reason - somehow DefaultController is being used instead of the one I've created... How do I fix that?

**UPDATE5:** I managed to solve the problem, although I don't know whether it's a good way to do that. I've changed the `src/Test/CalcBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` to look like this:

```
test_calc_homepage:
    pattern:  /Calc/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: TestCalcBundle:Calc:index }
```

**UPDATE6:** Solved - the problem was default controller left in routing.yml due to lack of understanding.

Comment: Please read through the excellent [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html). The cookbook teaches you the basics you need to work with SF2 in a breeze and by checking out the default installation, you get to play around the AcmeDemoBundle, where your question is basically implemented and thus answered. ;)

Comment: What does your routing (`app/config/routing.yml`) look like? And what do you want to change in the controller?

Comment: @nietonfir see Update2. I'd like to change anything, like add another exclamation mark - nothing reflects in the browser.

Comment: @Cababallero Concerning Update5: yep, that's exactly the way how you register another controller/route. Shame I didn't spotted that after you pasted `routing.yml`. -.-

Comment: @nietonfir I understand that, but what I don't understand is how a URL looks like to call function other than indexAction from the controller?

Comment: This is easy. Imagine your CalcController has `fooAction()` and you want the route to be `/example/foo`. All you have to do is register the route in `routing.yml` (or annotate the function if you use annotations): `some_unique_route_name: pattern: /example/foo defaults: { _controller: TestCalcBundle:Calc:foo }` (plz image the proper newlines ;-) )

Comment: Had the exact same issue, you should probably answer your own question  so the solution is easier to find :)

Answer (score 0):

Symfony has two access points to the application in the web dir

- `web/app.php` (this is for production the cache is active)
- `web/app_dev.php` (this is for dev the cache changes when you change something like templates, etc.)

point your browser to `http://localhost/app_dev.php`

you can get more information about environments in [Creating Pages in Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html)

you can check if your files are correct

### `app.php`

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

// Use APC for autoloading to improve performance.
// Change 'sf2' to a unique prefix in order to prevent cache key conflicts
// with other applications also using APC.
/*
$loader = new ApcClassLoader('sf2', $loader);
$loader->register(true);
*/

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
//require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

### `app_dev.php`

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

// If you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup for more information
//umask(0000);

// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'))
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
Debug::enable();

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

that are the files are have with sf 2.3.4

the projects with sf 2.3.* need the `Debug::enable();` line, check that line exists in your file

Comment: @Caballero did you clear your cache? `php app/console cache:clear`

Comment: @nietonfir Yes I did that before asking the question - didn't work.

Comment: @Caballero can you check your `app*.php` files and whats version of sf are using?

Comment: my app.php and app_dev.php files are identical to what you've pasted.

Comment: @rkmax I'm using version 2.3.5, the newest one. app*.php files are identical to what is pasted in this answer.

Comment: @Caballero i can find any reported bug about this, i'm installing a windows vm for check

Comment: @rkmax please see my Update4, found the reason, but not the fix (so far)

Comment: yeah @Caballero i see